Copying from comments to answer
I was trying to copy a comment in order to add it to an answer but I couldn’t get this to work. 
I can use the copy button from the comments context menu, but when I try to paste it into an answer I obtain just empty text. 
Perhaps I’m wrong but this seems a bug to me. 
I’m using the iPhone SO app, and I would like to know if it happens to someone else, and if it also happens on Android phones. 

Confirmed on iOS.

I don't have this problem with my Android phone.

@Charo Should I escalate this issue to SO Meta? I think it would also apply to other SO sites...

@abarisone: I suppose the same thing happens in other SE sites, so it may be a good idea to post the question in Meta.SE.
